# Appropriate use of the [tag] syntax in questions

Tags: discussion, tags, asking-questions

Is it appropriate to use [tag] in question text:

*This is an example [discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/discussion) on when to use [tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tags) in [asking-questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/asking-questions)*

I personally like it as it creates a kind of "wiki" feel and can sometimes justify when a certain tag has been added to a question.  However I haven't seen many questions make use of it.

Is there a guideline for when it is or is not appropriate to use [tag]?

Answer (score 3):

**Guideline:** don't be annoying.

Generally, you'll want to make sure to link the *first* mention of a tag. Further mentions usually don't need it - folks can click the first one if they wish to review the tag. This keeps the page uncluttered while still providing quick access to the tag being referenced.

Of course, using tag links for [things-that-are-not-tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/things-that-are-not-tags) is annoying - so don't do it.

Comment: I hadn't even realized you could put [tag:anything-in-a-tag].  Why would that even be allowed?

Comment: You can put [anything in a link too](http://thisisnotareallink.io) - there are occasionally good reasons for this, but doing it intentionally (as I just did) isn't wise.

Comment: Should tags only be used to refer to sections of SO as opposed to referring to the concept?

Comment: You can use them to refer to the concept if there's a plausible need for using the questions so-tagged on SO to help *explain* the concept. For instance, *"Disabling the browser's back button is rude. Instead, consider using [tag:redirect-after-post]!"*